# Using searchFiles or getFilesByName isn't yielding any results

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a script that will sort large numbers of photos and videos on Google Drive into folders that make it easier for my wife to find what she's looking for. Unfortunately, she has to use Drive rather than Google Photos, so she doesn't have access to the much more robust sorting functionality that Photos would give her.

Warning: I'm not a programmer, so I really don't know what I'm doing. I *think* I'm telling the script what folder to look in and then telling it to search for files that meet certain criteria in terms of name of the file, but the script is returning null from its search results.

I have tried using both searchFiles (with "name contains [my string var]" as the param), and getFilesByName (with my string var as the param). In both cases, I'm getting named folders but no files.

```
      var currDate = strMonth + strDay;
      var photos = currFolder.getFilesByName(
        "" + "2019" + currDate + "");

      var activeFolder = currFolder.createFolder(currDate);
      if (photos.hasNext()) {
        myLog = Logger.log("HasNext");

      } else {
        myLog = Logger.log("Doesn't HasNext");
      }
      while ( photos.hasNext() ) {
        var currPhoto = photos.next();
        currPhoto.makeCopy(activeFolder);
        myLog = Logger.log(currPhoto);
      }
```

What I expect is that photos is a list of pictures the script has found, that can then be copied over to the folder I created. My debug logging always tells me hasNext() is FALSE, though, and this seems to agree with the fact that no files are getting copied into the folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure I'm just doing something dumb. Thanks!

Comment: If Cooper's answer has fixed your problem, you should mark it as correct.  If not, you should add a comment to his answer explaining why it does not work

Answer (score 0):

**Here's an example that will display all of your JPEG files**

```
function findJPEGFiles() {
  var files=DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
  var html='<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Id</th><th>Url</th></tr>';
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file=files.next();
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getUrl());
  }
  html+='</table>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Files');
}
```