# Fix on_click function to change text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, dom-events

When I click on a button, a function is run. This function generates a string, and I am trying to display this string to the user in the div tag.

I tried to debug this in a few ways. For example, I check that the onclick is working. So, when I click the button, I do see "Clicked!" and then "In Function". This is expected. However, after that, it is supposed to display the string generated by the listAllEvents function. However, it does not seem to be working properly. (It logs the result as expected; it just doesn't display on the screen.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "Clicked!";
            listAllEvents()
        }


    function listAllEvents() {
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "In Function!";
        var calendarId = 'primary';
        var now = new Date();
        var display = ""
        var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
            timeMin: now.toISOString(),
            maxResults: 2500,
        });
        if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
                var event = events.items[i];

                if (event.start.date) {
                    // All-day event.
                    var start = new Date(event.start.date);
                    var end = new Date(event.end.date);
                    display = display + 'Start: ' + start.toLocaleDateString() + '; End: ' + end.toLocaleDateString() + ". ";
                } else {
                    var start = new Date(event.start.dateTime);
                    var end = new Date(event.end.dateTime);
                    display = display + 'Start: ' + start.toLocaleString() + '; End: ' + end.toLocaleString() + ". ";
                }
            }
        } else {
            display = 'No events found.';
        }

        Logger.log('%s ', display);
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "Almost There";
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = display;
    }
</script>

<div id="data"> Hello! </div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Run Function</button>
```

Expected, on click: Start....End.

Actual: "In Function!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Can't use server side code on the client**

The problem is that your trying to run server side code on the client.

```
   function listAllEvents() {
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "In Function!";
        var calendarId = 'primary';
        var now = new Date();
        var display = ""
        var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {//This is server side Google Script
            timeMin: now.toISOString(),
            maxResults: 2500,
        });
        if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
                var event = events.items[i];

                if (event.start.date) {
                    // All-day event.
                    var start = new Date(event.start.date);
                    var end = new Date(event.end.date);
                    display = display + 'Start: ' + start.toLocaleDateString() + '; End: ' + end.toLocaleDateString() + ". ";
                } else {
                    var start = new Date(event.start.dateTime);
                    var end = new Date(event.end.dateTime);
                    display = display + 'Start: ' + start.toLocaleString() + '; End: ' + end.toLocaleString() + ". ";
                }
            }
        } else {
            display = 'No events found.';
        }

        Logger.log('%s ', display);
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "Almost There";
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = display;
    }
```

When you want to run server side google script you can call them with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Here's a simple example of how to use [google.script.run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54800028/7215091)

This is the basic frame work:

Your html file:

The button click calls the Javascript function getCalendarEvents which prepares the appropriate (probably not required in this case) data to pass to the server and then it calls listCalendarEvents which is on the server.  The server function gets the events and returns them to the withSuccessHandler and that handler then puts the information into the html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function getCalendarEvents() {
           google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(function(eObj){
             //load html with data from eObj
           })
           .listCalendarEvents();
        }


    function listAllEvents() {

    }
</script>

<div id="data"> Hello! </div>
<button onclick="getCalendarEvents();">Run Function</button>
```

code.js:

```
function listCalendarEvents() {
 //get all of the events
 return eObj;
}
```

Comment: Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56212289/7215091) of how you can take spreadsheet data and integrated into an html table. And then display it on a dialog which is displayed clientside on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because `Calendar` is `undefined`. Your browser's *console* will tell you.